# Postgresql escape single quote in where clause

Tags: sql, postgresql

so I am trying to run a script like this one:

```
select id
from owner 
where owner.name = "john's"
```

and I am getting this error: `ERROR: column "john's" does not exist`.

Also I tried like this: `where owner.name = 'john\'s'`, but it dit not work

Anyone knows how I can run a query like this one?

Comment: try double single quotes  = "john ' ' s"?

Comment: `e'john\'s'` should do the trick. (the e prefix allows c-style backslash quoting(and other things) in string literals)

Comment: Single quotes go around string literals in Postgres. To escape a single quote inside your string literal, use two single quotes: `'John''s'`

Comment: Double single quotes inside the string literal, i.e. `where owner.name = 'john''s'`

Comment: If everything else fails, read the manual: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS

Answer (score 64):

You can escape single quotes when you double them.
For example:

```
= 'john''s'
```

Comment: can you mention how to escape double quotes?

Comment: is there a way to also then use a parameter like $1 inside the single quotes?

Answer (score 10):

Try this

```
select id
from owner 
where owner.name = (E'john\'s')::text
```

Update:
we can escape most of the characters using  this statement

```
select id
from owner 
where owner.name = (E'john\character you want to escape's')::text
```