# How to find in postgres strings like %'%

Tags: postgresql, escaping

I need to search in my column strings which contains '

```
select * from app_user au where au.last_name like '%'%'
```

but something like that gives me

```
SQL Error [42601]: Unterminated string literal started at position 55
```

I tried also '%\'%', but it's not working too, how to escape ' in postgres?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace apostrophe in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45758536/replace-apostrophe-in-string) [Insert text with single quotes in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316953/insert-text-with-single-quotes-in-postgresql) [Postgresql escape single quote in where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38700966/postgresql-escape-single-quote-in-where-clause)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To escape `'`, you need to add it twice. Use `''` to resolve it.

```
select * from app_user au where au.last_name like '%''%'
```

Comment: @nbk the game ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to double the single quote to get the result

```
CREATE TABLE app_user (last_name text)
```

```
INSERT INTO app_user VALUES ('ma''affee')
```

```
select * from app_user au where au.last_name like '%''%'
```

| last_name |
| --- |
| ma'affee |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/aSJocx78)

As you see in the sample the INSERT needs also a double single quote, but prepare statements with parameters will take the need to double single quote away when inserting or selecting